# How to do a line fit using least square fitting?

Tags: julia, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a line segment using least square fitting. The line segment looks something like following:

[image: Line Semgnet]

```
using LsqFit
img=load("img_file.jpg")
nodes=findall(img.>0)
xdata=map(p->p[2], nodes)
ydata=map(p->p[2], nodes)
p=[0.5,0.5]#nodes[1]
m(t, p) = p[1] * exp.(p[2] * t)
fit = curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p)

## Inf values if i change the value of p to be node[1]
fit = curve_fit(m, xdata, ydata, [8.0,273.0])
```

I'm trying to fit a polynomial line on these cartesianIndexes in 'nodes' using `curve_fit` as shown in https://julianlsolvers.github.io/LsqFit.jl/latest/tutorial/  I'm not sure how to pass parameters to it? Or how should i analyze the results of how the new line looks like and what are its new cartesianIndexes?

[image]
[image: Inf values]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to fit a polynomial line on these cartesianIndexes...

```
using Images, Polynomials, Plots

img = load("jTjYb.png")
img = Gray.(img)
img = img[end:-1:1, :]
nodes = findall(img.>0)

xdata = map(p->p[2], nodes)
ydata = map(p->p[1], nodes)
f = fit(xdata, ydata, 2)

plot(f, extrema(xdata)..., size=(800, 500))
```

[image]

If you change the plot's `size=(120, 200)` and turn the `label=false` and the degree of the polynomial to `3` rather than `2`, and try to compare the result:
[image]

code:

```
f = fit(xdata, ydata, 3)
plot(f, extrema(xdata)..., size=(120, 200), label=false)
```

If you want to achieve `y` values by the fitted Polynomial, then follow the next:

```
fx(data, cCoef, bCoef, aCoef) = @. data^2 *aCoef + xdata*bCoef + cCoef';

julia> unique(fx(xdata, f.coeffs...))
91-element Vector{Float64}:
  -4.235708042623974
  -0.8388324947906831
   2.5201535732455502
   5.84125016148472
   9.124457269926829
  12.369774898571883
  15.577203047419875
  18.746741716470805
  21.878390905724675
  24.972150615181487
  28.02802084484124
  31.046001594703935
  34.02609286476956
   ⋮
 147.3799729814638
 147.78357962532934
 148.14929678939782
 148.47712447366925
 148.76706267814362
 149.0191114028209
 149.23327064770115
 149.40954041278434
 149.54792069807044
 149.64841150355952
 149.71101282925153
 149.73572467514643
```

Comment: Thanks, JUL when I convert those y values into cartesianIndex, they round off and the line is broken. I used ydata_new .= round.(Int, f.(xdata)) here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75130618/linefitting-how-to-deal-with-continuous-values?noredirect=1#comment132581962_75130618]