# Linefitting how to deal with continuous values?

Tags: image-processing, julia

I'm trying to fit a line using quadratic poly, but because the fit results in continuous values, the integer conversion (for CartesianIndex) rounds it off, and I loose data at that pixel.

I tried the method
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104844/how-to-do-a-line-fit-using-least-square-fitting/75105266#75105266). So I get new y values as

```
using Images, Polynomials, Plots,ImageView

img = load("jTjYb.png")
img = Gray.(img)
img = img[end:-1:1, :]
nodes = findall(img.>0)

xdata = map(p->p[2], nodes)
ydata = map(p->p[1], nodes)
f = fit(xdata, ydata, 2)
ydata_new .= round.(Int, f.(xdata)
new_line_fitted_img=zeros(size(img))
new_line_fitted_img[xdata,ydata_new].=1
imshow(new_line_fitted_img)
```

which results in chopped line as below

[image] whereas I was expecting it to be continuous line as it was in pre-processing

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear what you are doing and what you're asking. You have a function, and you plot a single dot for each integer x value? But instead you'd like to plot a continuous line? Is this just about plotting?

Comment: Why are using `ceil`? Isn't `round` more appropriate? You don't need the loop, btw. Does this work for you? `ydata_new .= round.(Int, f.(xdata))`.

Comment: @DNF Thanks, that works too. However, I'm still getting broken line.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hey Cris I've updated the question with more detail.

Comment: But you still provide no code where you even attempt to plot `f`?

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t know what you want to accomplish. Do you need to have a list with all the points on the line? Do you need to draw the polynomial in an image? Do you want to have a sampled representation of the polynomial?

Comment: Your just creating a dotted image, that won't do. You must use `plot`, not `imshow`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've the list of all points using ydata_new. However, due to rounding off, some ydata_new values e.g.[212.12,212,14,212,13..] all get rounded to 121 (Integer). This leaves a gap in the line. Does this explanation help?

Comment: @DNF I'm working with finetuning the image curve, so I need to use imshow, right? Plot wouldn't give an image?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an image (basically, a matrix) instead of a line plot? One way to not have a 'broken' line is to allow multiple y-values for each x-value, but when you do the `fit`, you get one y-value per x-value. The other way is to upsample your grid so densely that you cannot see that the fitted line is 'broken'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect the following:

| Raw Image | Fitted Polynomial | Superposition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Code:

```
using Images, Polynomials

img = load("img.png");
img = Gray.(img)

fx(data, dCoef, cCoef, bCoef, aCoef) = @. data^3 *aCoef + data^2 *bCoef + data*cCoef + dCoef;

function fit_poly(img::Array{<:Gray, 2})
  img = img[end:-1:1, :]
  nodes = findall(img.>0)
  xdata = map(p->p[2], nodes)
  ydata = map(p->p[1], nodes)
  f = fit(xdata, ydata, 3)
  xdt = unique(xdata)
  xdt, fx(xdt, f.coeffs...)
end;


function draw_poly!(X, y)
  the_min = minimum(y)
  if the_min<0
    y .-= the_min - 1
  end
  initialized_img = Gray.(zeros(maximum(X), maximum(y)))
  initialized_img[CartesianIndex.(X, y)] .= 1
  dif = diff(y)
  for i in eachindex(dif)
    the_dif = dif[i]
    if abs(the_dif) >= 2
      segment = the_dif ÷ 2
      initialized_img[i, y[i]:y[i]+segment] .= 1
      initialized_img[i+1, y[i]+segment+1:y[i+1]-1] .= 1
    end
  end
  rotl90(initialized_img)
end;

X, y = fit_poly(img);
y = convert(Vector{Int64}, round.(y));
draw_poly!(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand a couple of things. What is the_min<0 check for and what is it doing y .-= the_min - 1? Also what is diff(y) for?

Comment: Also in case fx(xdata...) returns quadratic polynomial, how should the function fx be changed to cater for that?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've modified some bits and it suits. :)